# how to refer to data of referenced node

Tags: hooks, nodes, forms

In drupal 6, I have an event node type and an event_attend node type.

The event_attend node type has a nodereference to event. In hook_form_alter for the event_attend node type, i added a validation routine.

In the validation routine, i would like to have access to the parent event node. I would like to compare event_attend's date of participation to the date when the event is taking place.

Is there a way of doing this without doing a node_load($nid_of_parent_event)?

I was kind of hoping that somewhere in the $form variable lies data for the parent event's date but I think such is not the case. That is why I am posting the question here.

I am using openatrium 6x by the way. Anyway, I'll just make a query directly to the database to get the parent event's date using the event nid.

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 6, the standard way of doing this is by using the following function:

```
node_load($nid = NULL, $vid = NULL, $reset = FALSE)
```

However if you want to implement it in Drupal 7, it becomes a lot easier using the Views and the References module. All you need to do is :

1. Create two different content types say a and b and add fields to them. You MUST add a node reference field(say to b)
2. A pop up would ask you to choose which node you would like to reference(choose a here)
   After that if you wish to look for some advanced settings, you can add [Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/relationship) depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1.In Drupal 7,With the help of **Reference**s module,you can refer one **CONTENT TYPE to ANOTHER CONTENT TYPE.**
2.Suppose you want to refer second content type from first content type.
3.Then,while creating first content type,create a field of type NODE REFERNCE.
4.Then ,while creating the content,just add the second content type which u want to be displayed.
5.you can also link two content types with views using this REFERENCES module and by adding contextual filters and adding a relationship.